# How to change the tick symbol of checkbox to "X"

Tags: vb6

I'm making a checksheet , in my checksheet there's a legend  ✓ = Ok , X = NG. Is it possible to change the tick symbol in vb6 checkbox ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the checkbox. Set its properties this way:

- **Style :** `1 - Graphical`
- **Picture :** a picture file representing "X"
- **DownPicture :** a picture file representing "✓"

Pictures can be icons (`*.ico`), cursors (`*.cur`), bitmaps (`*.bmp`, `*.gif`, `*.jpg`, etc.).

Note that since it uses bitmap type images and not vector ones, you'll deal with pixel sizes to design your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to mimic the desired behavior/optics with the `CommandButton` control, where you set its `Style` property to 2, set its `Picture` property to a matching image and swap that image if necessary:

```
Dim pic As StdPicture
Set pic = LoadPicture("C:\YourCheckmarkOrXImageFileHere.ico") Set
Command1.Picture = pic
```